# Laravel Pivot assign giving NULL result many to many

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot, relationship

i having trouble finding why service_id is returning null values

Services Model

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Categories', 'categories_services', 'services_id', 'categories_id');
}
```

Categories Model

```
protected $table = "categories";

public function services()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Services', 'categories_services', 'categories_id', 'services_id');
}
```

Services Controller

```
    $command = new \App\BizCommands\AddServices();
    $arr = $request->all();

    $arr["merchant_id"] = 1;
    $arr["peak_mode"] = 0;
    $arr["type"] = "SERVICE";
    $arr["tags"] = implode(",", $request->tags);
    $ret = $command->execute($arr, Auth::user());
    $ret->success = ($ret->error_code==0);

    $service = new Services;

    $service->categories()->attach($request->category_id);

    dd($service);
```

the categories_services table only get the id for the corresponding category id the newly inserted id for the service is resulting to null when inserted to categories_services.

any help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just created a new instance of services. So, I think it will be null. 
For example: If I have to insert a role for a user then I can do is

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

$user->roles()->attach($roleId);
```

It will insert the role_id. In your case you may do something like :

```
$service = new Service();
$service->name = $request->name;
$service->Save();

$service->categories()->attach($request->category_id);
```

Comment: well thats make sense now. thumbs up

Comment: If this helped you make sure you mark it correct @d'reaper